# SpringBoot @Autowire not working inside @Repository

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a multi module SpringBoot app with gradle and kotlin, trying spring-data-r2dbc. If i use @Repository annotation over my Repository class,  @Autowired DatabaseClient is null. But if i change annotation to @Component, @Autowired works and I do successfull call to database. Any idea why @Autowire isn't working with @Repository annotation?

Database configuration class:

```
@Configuration
open class DatabaseConfiguration(
    @Value("\${spring.data.mssql.host}") private val host: String,
   // @Value("\${spring.data.mssql.port}") private val port: Int,
    @Value("\${spring.data.mssql.database}") private val database: String,
    @Value("\${spring.data.mssql.username}") private val username: String,
    @Value("\${spring.data.mssql.password}") private val password: String)
: AbstractR2dbcConfiguration() {

@Bean
override fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
    return MssqlConnectionFactory(
            MssqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .host(host)
                    //.port(port)
                    .database(database)
                    .username(username)
                    .password(password).build()
    )
 }
}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
class MultigradleApplication
```

Repository class (in module "data"):

```
@Repository
open class TestRepo() {

@Autowired
lateinit var client: DatabaseClient

    fun getAll() : Flux<PersonDTO> {
            return client.execute("SELECT * FROM Person.Person")
                .`as`(PersonDTO::class.java)
                .fetch()
                .all()
    }
}
```

Comment: check the import statement to see if you have right `@Repository` annotation

Comment: @sidgate org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

Comment: Where are you injecting the  TestRepo or how are you accessing it?

Comment: And also can you add a `@PostConstruct`  method to your `TestRepo` and just do a print of if `client` is injected by that time. Just ensure you are using after it is fully initialzied

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai TestRepo is Autowired in PersonService class in "business" module. And PersonService class is Autowired in controller in main module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I injected PersonService as its IPersonService interface into my Controller, but I didn't have an interface for TestRepo and injected it directly. When I added ITestRepo interface to TestRepo and injected it into the service as ITestRepo, everything started working.